# Trigger a function if the number of rows increases

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like my function `sendSlackMessage` to fire only if the number of rows increases in a sheet.

I am using a code that was kindly provided by a member here, however, each time the code runs (time intervals each min), the rows number property increases by a wrong number; for example (stores old rows as 37.0 when it should be only 34.0)

What could be the issue here? Or how can I improve this code to go around this?

```
function checkNewRows() {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var oldRows = sp.getProperty("rows") || 0; 
  var newRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main").getLastRow();
  if (newRows > oldRows) {
    sp.setProperty("rows", newRows);
    sendSlackMessage();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When including content created by someone else please give proper attribution, otherwise it's plagiarism. Also Please add a brief description of your search efforts for helpful content from this site and show what you have tried to fix the issue as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show looks fine. The `rows` property does not tell the number of rows in data but the *last row number* that holds data. That should not make a difference to the results you get, as long as you are using the `rows` property consistently the same way.

In the event that your `sendSlackMessage()` function also reads the `rows` property and interprets it as something else than the row number of the last row, you may want to use a function parameter to convey the row number of the last row instead of reading and writing properties, like this:

```js
    sendSlackMessage(newRows);
```

If you absolutely need to record the number of data rows rather than the row number of the last row, you can use something like this:

```js
function checknumRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main');
  const props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const oldNumRows = props.getProperty('rows') || 0;
  const numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - sheet.getFrozenRows();
  if (numRows > oldNumRows) {
    props.setProperty('rows', numRows);
    sendSlackMessage(numRows);
  }
}
```

To set the number of header rows, use **View > Freeze**.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0') {
    var oldRows = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("rows") || 0;
    var newRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet0").getLastRow();
    if (newRows > oldRows) {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("rows", newRows);
      e.source.toast(`Old: ${oldRows} New: ${newRows}`)
    }
  }
}
```

If you are using array formula functions that can cause problems with calculation of getLastRow() method